# Phalcon save() fails silently

Tags: phalcon

I've tried everything I can think of, but cannot get the model->save() method to actually update certain columns in the database.  My Users model looks like this (using Phalcon Cashier):

```
<?php
namespace Vokuro\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Cashier\Billable;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;

/**
 * Vokuro\Models\Users
 * All the users registered in the application
 */
class Users extends Model
{

use Billable;

/**
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $id;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $name;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $email;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $password;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $mustChangePassword;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $profilesId;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $banned;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $suspended;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $active;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $stripe_id;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $card_brand;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $card_last_four;

/**
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $trial_ends_at;

/**
 * Before create the user assign a password
 */
public function beforeValidationOnCreate()
{
    if (empty($this->password)) {

        // Generate a plain temporary password
        $tempPassword = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12)));

        // The user must change its password in first login
        $this->mustChangePassword = 'Y';

        // Use this password as default
        $this->password = $this->getDI()
            ->getSecurity()
            ->hash($tempPassword);
    } else {
        // The user must not change its password in first login
        $this->mustChangePassword = 'N';
    }

    // The account must be confirmed via e-mail
    // Only require this if emails are turned on in the config, otherwise account is automatically active
    if ($this->getDI()->get('config')->useMail) {
        $this->active = 'N';
    } else {
        $this->active = 'Y';
    }

    // The account is not suspended by default
    $this->suspended = 'N';

    // The account is not banned by default
    $this->banned = 'N';

}

/**
 * Send a confirmation e-mail to the user if the account is not active
 */
public function sendConfirmationEmail()
{
    // Only send the confirmation email if emails are turned on in the config
    if ($this->getDI()->get('config')->useMail) {

        if ($this->active == 'N') {

            $emailConfirmation = new EmailConfirmations();

            $emailConfirmation->usersId = $this->id;

            if ($emailConfirmation->save()) {
                $this->getDI()
                    ->getFlash()
                    ->notice('A confirmation mail has been sent to ' . $this->email);

            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Validate that emails are unique across users
 */
public function validation()
{
    $validator = new Validation();

    $validator->add('email', new Uniqueness([
        "message" => "The email is already registered"
    ]));

    return $this->validate($validator);
}

public function subscription()
{
  $users = Users::find();
  $user = $users->getLast();
  $result = $user->newSubscription('main', '2017 Online Individual')->create($this->getTestToken());
  return $result;
}

protected function getTestToken()
{
    return \Stripe\Token::create([
        'card' => [
            'number' => '4242424242424242',
            'exp_month' => 5,
            'exp_year' => 2020,
            'cvc' => '123',
        ],
    ], ['api_key' => 'sk_test_98CUmA7w2JTAp25qVyMZweM9'])->id;
}


public function initialize()
{

    $this->belongsTo('profilesId', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Profiles', 'id', [
        'alias' => 'profile',
        'reusable' => true
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\SuccessLogins', 'usersId', [
        'alias' => 'successLogins',
        'foreignKey' => [
            'message' => 'User cannot be deleted because he/she has activity in the system'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\PasswordChanges', 'usersId', [
        'alias' => 'passwordChanges',
        'foreignKey' => [
            'message' => 'User cannot be deleted because he/she has activity in the system'
        ]
    ]);

    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\ResetPasswords', 'usersId', [
        'alias' => 'resetPasswords',
        'foreignKey' => [
            'message' => 'User cannot be deleted because he/she has activity in the system'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

}

After creating a Stripe user/subscription and returning the Customer ID (stripe_id), Last 4 (card_last_four), etc..., this function, I want to save all that to the database in the SessionController before forwarding to the IndexController.

```
public function subscribeAction($user)
{

  $subscribe = $user->subscription();

  $user->save();

  return $this->dispatcher->forward([
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
  ]);
```

The user name, password, etc all save fine, but I cannot get the stripe specific columns to update.  They remain null unless I run a terminal command to change them.  I have also been able to successfully update them using save if I wait until after a user is created, then login, and run something like:

```
$user = $this->auth->getUser();

$user->stripe_id = "123";

$user->save();
```

Comment: try dumping the result of the save with `var_dump($user->save());die;` and see what the error message says

Comment: It just gives a boolean true.

Comment: That's kind of the weird part to me.  No exceptions or errors.  It just doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: `save()` function returns a boolean of `false` if it fails. To get SQL errors that disturbed saving data, you can print `getMessages()`. If it always return `true`, it means that save was correct, but you may have something declared along your model, that prevents saving `stripe_id` part. Check if you are setting it up for sure before trying to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ($user->save($_POST) === false) {
     $messages = $user->getMessages();

     $errorMsg = '';
     foreach ($messages as $message) {
         $errorMsg . "{$message} <br>";
     }
     $this->flashSession->error("Error: $errorMsg");
}
```

Then in your view put

```
<?php $this->flashSession->output() ?>
```

Comment: I did this, and got "trial_ends_at is required".  So, I went in and manually set that variable as a current timestamp just before the save.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say what's going on exactly, but it almost looks to me like you're in an uncommitted database transaction. You say the fields are saving when you create the account but not after you call a method on the Billable trait as part of Cashier. Also the save() method is returning true, which means Phalcon *thinks* the record is saved. I don't see any code in Cashier that explicitly starts a transaction, though I haven't looked in much depth.

Here's how you can test my theory. Use the transaction system in Phalcon to switch from implicit to explicit

`use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Transaction\Manager as TxManager;`

Then in your subscribeAction method:

```
public function subscribeAction($user)
{
  $manager = new TxManager();

  // Request a transaction
  $transaction = $manager->get();

  $subscribe = $user->subscription();

  $user->save();

  $transaction->commit();

  return $this->dispatcher->forward([
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
  ]);
}
```

The transaction system is designed to help avoid conflicting writes or race conditions by ensuring that everything you write during your transaction is available on an all-or-nothing basis, and not until you explicitly commit. Especially when dealing with commerce, this can help you avoid having one table say a purchase was made while another doesn't have any record of the payment during that split second that it's being processed.

[This page](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/model-transactions.html) has more detail on how transactions are used with Phalcon.

Comment: So, I implemented this and dumped the result of the commit, which was a boolean TRUE.  Still getting NULLs in the database. Maybe I'm not initializing the model correctly or something.

Comment: Were the values you were trying to insert ever added to the $user object? You say you're getting nulls in the database. Dump the actual values that you're expecting to see, for example `echo $user->stripe_id` right before your save. From your other post I thought you weren't getting anything in the database at all.

Comment: Here's what I ran:

 `public function subscribeAction($user)
    {
       $manager = new TxManager();

  // Request a transaction
  $transaction = $manager->get();

  $subscribe = $user->subscription();

  $dump = $subscribe->stripe_id;

  var_dump($dump);

  $subscribe->save();

  $trans = $transaction->commit();
  exit;

  return $this->dispatcher->forward([
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
  ]);
}`

The subscription() function return the User object.  The dump gives the correct value, but still getting NULL in the database.

Comment: What database are you connecting to? Assuming Mysql,  run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and paste the results here. That might provide more insight into why this is not saving. (if you're not using mysql run the equivalent for your database)

Answer (score -1):

I've had this same issue as well. After some tweaking of the database, the problem is that we have two auto number fields on the same table.

Usually the first one is the primary key. If we delete or change the second auto number field to normal then the problem is gone.

Answer (score -2):

moi jai une seurueux probleme avec save() mais lorsque je capture l'érreur il m'envois un false je ne comprend pas voici mon code initiale

```
  // Création du membre
         $membre = new Membre();    
          
        $membre->nom = $data['nom'];
        $membre->prenom = $data['prenom'];
        $membre->pseudo = $data['pseudo'];
        $membre->email = $data['email'];
        $membre->mdp = $data['mdp'];
        $membre->email = $data['email'];
        //$membre->civilite = $data['civilite'];
        $membre->ville = $data['ville'];
        $membre->code_postal = $data['code_postal'];
        //$membre->adresse = $data['adresse'];


       var_dump($membre->save());die;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [This is an English-language site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577). Please translate your question into English.